# What the difference between zend framework and Wordpress as framework?

Tags: wordpress, zend-framework

I only know Wordpress and have started to seek another alternative framework, Zend. I have heard hearsay that Zend is better than other frameworks.  If you are "a serious coder", or try to act like one, you need to use it for building your web app.

Some say Zend is better but it is subjective. It is fast and secure but nobody has given a reason or at least compared it with with Wordpress.

Ultimate question : Does Zend have themes or plugins just like Wordpress ?

Any hint will be helpful

edit. **maybe it's stupid, but it's a question. if you don't like it, or you feel it's offensive then down-vote. I don't mind ;). No hard feelings**

Comment: Is this a real question?

Comment: yes it is a question. a stupid one. but still a question ;). my own stupid question.

Comment: it's a valid question IMO, but it doesn't prevent you from writing real words and correct sentences

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're comparing apples and oranges.  Wordpress is not a framework, it's a publishing tool.  The only thing you can do with Wordpress is make blogs.

A framework is a set of code that provides you with tools to build things.  Zend Framework is a web framework that lets you build web applications.  In fact, you could *build Wordpress* using Zend Framework (and it would probably be way better than its current sad design).  You could build any other kind of site with Zend Framework.  What Zend doesn't do is provide you with a bunch of pre-built web pages and templates and content management systems... those are all publishing tools (which you could build with a framework).

In short, you can't build a web app with Wordpress, since it's not a framework, and Zend doesn't have themes because it's a coding tool.

Comment: do zend have a pluggin or the zend library will work as a pluggin ?

Comment: "The only thing you can do with Wordpress is make blogs." False

"...you can't build a web app with Wordpress..." False
"...you could build Wordpress using Zend Framework (and it would probably be way better than its current sad design)..."  subjective

Answer (score 7):

You are asking the difference between Ferrari and the tomato. Both are red, but…

- Zend Framework is a [Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_framework)
- Wordpress is a [Blog software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blog_software)

You may write app like Wordpress using ZF, but not vice versa.

Comment: But you can't build Ferrari using only tomato :)

Answer (score 4):

Wordpress is a content management system. It is much more specialized than Zend, which is a generic application framework.

You could build a cms with Zend for example. But you would have to build it from the ground.

Answer (score 3):

I dissagree that Wordpress is not a framework. As a developer you can develop plugins into wordpress that can do some pretty neat things. Okay, you may say that wordpress is not a framework itself, but it does provide a development framework that allows developers to tap into. True it started life as blogging software, but to limit wordpress to only blogs is not doing wordpress the justice it deserves.

Zend_Framework on the other hand is completely different to wordpress. Zend_Framework will help your web development, but it wont do it for you. Where wordpress will work as a content management system/blog out of the box leaving the developer with a plugin framework to allow you to build custom modules and code that will run within wordpress, Zend_Framework will expect you to build everything from scratch. Sure it will provide some helper classes to help you along the way, but its up to the developer to pretty much write their entire application from scratch using Zend tools.

Personally speaking if you want complete and utter control over your entire application, and want to do everything from scratch with some help from Zend, then Zend_Framework is a tool you might want to investigate. If however you just want a website with a little customisation, then wordpress is a very good tool for that.

But the two dont compare side by side, they are different solutions for different problems.

Comment: i agree with this answer because wordpress is not only for blogs anymore,there are bug tracking systems developed with wordpress, e-commerce and much more.

Answer (score 2):

Zend is an application framework. WordPress is a buggy blog manager. If you don't know the difference, then you probably have no reason to use Zend.

Comment: +1 for harc cold true. i have reason to use it cause wordpress as you said little bit buggy. i have hard time to custom it's dashboard. even though now it's not a problem.

Answer (score 2):

There appears to be a project called [Zendpress](http://www.zendpress.org/) to create a Wordpress-like blog platform built on Zend Framework. Strikes me as a great idea, though at present, there doesn't seem to be any significant activity there.

Answer (score -4):

If you are a coder you can use Wordpress to build any web apps easily. Zend framework is the old fashion way to build web based apps. To this date, Wordpress is getting more powerful and flexible which you can use on any web developments. It is not only a CMS.

Comment: "Zend framework is the old fashion way to build web based apps" is not even remotely defensible and extremely misleading.

Comment: This really is a terrible answer. You most certainly cannot use WordPress to build any web app easily. Anyone trying to do something too far from WordPress's core functionality with it is in for a world of pain. You can extend it by writing themes and plugins, but it soon reaches a point where you'd be much better off using a modern MVC framework. And saying any framework is the old-fashioned way to build web apps compared to WordPress is just laughable.